# Is there a possibility to delay a WCF service response without blocking a worker thread

Tags: multithreading, wcf, iis, c#-4.0

Yes, it sounds pretty sensless but I have the actual requirement to delay the response of an WCF service for at least seven seconds. This is done now with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` which is said to be blocking. Therefore I would like to find a solution that leaves the worker thread available for other requests. I also tried `System.Timer` which turned out to be blocking as well.

I am aware of the possiblity to send a request, communicate the time to wait to the client and perform a second request after the time has passed. But that would require to validate the time waited, store and resend various data and validate that it has not changed. I would like to investigate first if this is really necessary.

Comment: Attaching an event to a System.Threading.Timer that triggers after 7 second could be an option?

Comment: @Gabber: As mentioned above, I tried this and it seems to be blocking as well (as it uses up another thread to host the `Timer`) and therefore defeats the purpose.

Comment: @paramosh: WCF service is hosted in IIS 7.0 / 7.5 running in integrated mode.

Comment: Ok, just pointed out because System.Timer and System.Threading.Timer differ quite a bit, didn't understand that launching another thread made the application hang. My last try would be something like  "while(DateTime.Now<datetimesevensecondslater){ Application.DoEvents(); }" but something like that would work in win forms, not sure in WCF

Comment: @Gabber: Care to elaborate difference between `System.Timer` and `System.Threading.Timer`? In WCF there is no `Application.DoEvents()` and your while loop would result in busy waiting. Not good. And launching another thread does not make the application hang unless all threads in the thread pool are used up (which is an issue here).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the client is expecting a *synchronous* call, you're stuck holding on to a thread until the request is processed and the response returned. You could try exotic hacks like implementing [IInstanceProvider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/31/wcf-extensibility-iinstanceprovider.aspx) or creating an operation behavior to handle the required time delay but in the end, you're still holding on to a thread.

Comment: Well, that's what I think as well. But there is no necessity to perform a synchronous call. Are there other possibilities then?

Comment: Conceptually, a solution would be to create a request handler that places requests in a queue on reciept and then only executes requests that have "matured" an appropriate amount of time. I don't know if it is feasible to create a non-blocking request scheduler within or leveraging the WCF asynchronous plumbing. It seems that managing multiple requests from the client to handle the time delay is an easier problem to solve than trying a service-side solution with WCF :)

Comment: You are probably right! THX! Just thought there may be some programmatic construct i'm not aware of that solves such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the problem correctly, I assume that you don't want to block the service and you want to allow multiple clients to acess the service concurrently.

What are your concurrency settings for the service? You may want to have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and) or at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) for further information about the subject.

Comment: Please be aware that this is a solution to a service side issue, though I'm still not sure where you are calling Thread.Sleep(): are you blocking the client or the service? How are you instantiating the service now? With a bit more info we could probably help you more efficiently.

Comment: The WCF service is called from JavaScript (which works async) on a web page. `Thread.Sleep()` is called in the WCF service to delay the response (due to some real life correlation) so that basically the JavaScript end receives the result some 7 seconds later.

Comment: @PrinceCharles: See what happens if you use the following attribute on your service (see first link for explanation, section "Instance mode = Per Call and Concurrency = Multiple"): [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall, 
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if somebody will need such (strange) possibility...

As for me, it works with attribute

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

on service class and

```
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

before method's return;